# How to set the working precision globally? $MinPrecision does not work

Tags: arbitrary-precision, precision-and-accuracy

I want to increase the precision globally to `50` at least, but `$MinPrecision` does not work.

```
$MinPrecision = 50;
x = Sin[2.]
(* -> 0.909297 *)

Precision[x]
(* -> MachinePrecision *)
```

How to set the working precision globally, i.e., make all the calculations in the notebook use the new precision?

Comment: Hope this helps, have a look at: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6421/global-precision-setting

Comment: Precision settings only apply for arbitrary-precision values. When working with machine numbers, there is no tracking or adjustment of precision. So, enter your value as e.g. `2.\`16` rather than `2.` and you will get the effect you are after.

Comment: My notebook involves machine precision numbers in many places; it would be tedious if I do the change like 2.`16 in every place. Is there a convenient way to set the precision once and for all?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This looks like a duplicate of my question here [Global precision setting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6421/global-precision-setting) . Since I formulated it in a slightly different way, coming from Maple it might however be worth quoting the answer given by Mr. Wizard here. It worked for me in Mathematica 9 if there are no arbitary precision numbers in the notebook (defined as e.g. 2.`16):

```
$PreRead = (# /. 
 s_String /; 
   StringMatchQ[s, NumberString] && 
    Precision@ToExpression@s == MachinePrecision :> s <> "`50." &);

3/1.5 + Pi/7

Precision[%]
```

This will act on all later commands before the actual command is executed and set the precision of contained numerical values to 50 digits.