# Huge bug involving MultinormalDistribution?

Tags: bugs, probability-or-statistics, distributions

**Bug introduced in 8.0 and fixed in 11.1**

---

I found a strange behavior regarding the CDF of the bivariate Normal distribution

```
CDF[MultinormalDistribution[{0,0},({{1,37/40},{37/40,1}})],{0,0.2}]
```

gives

```
0.446357
```

On the other hand, the direct way

```
NIntegrate[PDF[MultinormalDistribution[{0,0},({{1,37/40},{37/40,1}})],{x, y}],{x,-\[Infinity],0},{y,-\[Infinity],0.2}]
```

gives

```
0.470073
```

which is right, confirmed by R software and other programs.

What the hell is going on here?

Comment: Please do not add the [tag:bugs] tag when you post a new question.  It is a special tag that is meant to be added by someone else than the original asker.

Comment: Problem is that .2  Try CDF[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 
   0}, ({{1, 37/40}, {37/40, 1}})], {0, .200000000000000000000}], yields 0.4700730326142416330 on my machine.

Comment: Not on my system. I'm using Version 8.0.

Comment: What does this get for you N[CDF[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 
   0}, ({{1, 37/40}, {37/40, 1}})], {0, 1/5}],20]

Comment: Thanks, surprisingly 0.47007303261424163299, but why is that?

Comment: Somebody better at teaching in here than me can write a nice answer why it is not surprising. My one liner ain't good enough to be an answer.

Comment: It appears that when calculations are done with machine precision, something goes very wrong.  When they are done in arbitrary precision, all is fine, even if the precision is low.  I suspect that entirely different methods are used in the two cases, and I don't think that this is due to precision loss.

Comment: If you look at this plot, those cusps shouldn't be there.  They should be "round". `ContourPlot[
 CDF[d, {x, y}],
 {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All, MaxRecursion -> 3
 ]`.  Does look like a bug. Please do report this to Wolfram Support.

Comment: @Szabolcs that integral might be chewing up lots of digits. Numerical integration can be tricky. Sorry, did not see your added comments in time.

Comment: @bobbym This is not a hard integral numerically and I'm not even sure it internally uses simple integration for this ... also, `Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 0}, N[CDF[d, {0, 1/2}], 6]]` gives the correct result and it only has 6 digits to work with, much less than the 15 digits machine precision has.

Comment: My concern is that many scientists like me used these very basic functions, their results might be corrupted.

Comment: @Szabolcs nevertheless it is always a good starting place when a argument is entered like .2 to start right there and try other ideas. I know you know that already so I am just making the point in passing.

Comment: @fwgb Hamming said the purpose of computing is insight not numbers. You have to learn to mistrust computers too.

Comment: @bobbym Good quote. You never stop learning. I'm goint to contact Support.

Comment: @bobbym He also said, many years later, "The purpose of computing numbers is not yet in sight."

Comment: Also `Probability[
 x <= 0 \[And] y <= 0.2, {x, y} \[Distributed] 
  MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, 37/40}, {37/40, 1}}]]` and `NProbability[
 x <= 0 \[And] y <= 0.2, {x, y} \[Distributed] 
  MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, 37/40}, {37/40, 1}}]]` give different results.

Comment: People who are voting to close as "simple mistake":  what exactly is the mistake here?  I don't see why this is the OP's mistake.  It looks like a bug to me.  A very disturbing bug that could invalidate results, as the OP said.  I don't see good evidence that this is really a precision loss issue.  Maybe it is, but I am not convinced.

Comment: So the problem is that 'CDF[Multinormal...]' can go completely wrong at 'MachinePrecision'. Not really a simple mistake...

Comment: @Szabolcs Unfortunately I don't have access to any Mathematica licence for a few months (*sniff*) so I can't try it but won't the argument of the $N$ simplify to something algebraic in your example? Then `$MaxExtraPrecision` would only apply to the latter, which is a different problem.

Comment: @TheVee No, it doesn't in this particular case.  (In other cases it does, not in this particular example.)

Comment: I read "Bug introduced in 8.0 or **earlier**..." but the word EARLIER surprises me very much. Earlier than 8.0 it was 7.0.1. Today I have Mathematica 7.0.1 at hand, on Windows 7x64, I check the subject problem `CDF[MultinormalDistribution[{0,0},({{1,37/40},{37/40,1}})],{0,0.2}]` and get the correct result `0.470073`, the same as from using `NIntegrate`. Therefore the statement about "earlier" seems to be incorrect.

Comment: Thank you! That was added by an admin. Good to know that only 8 and younger are affected.

Comment: @fwgb Thank you for the reporting the issue. It has now been addressed in the sources and the fix will become available in the next release. The bug affects machine precision computation for $\rho^2 > 0.95^2$. Please use computation at `$MachinePrecision` as a temporary work-around.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I almost believe the precision argument.  But not quite.

```
dist = MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, ({{1, 37/40}, {37/40, 1}})];
CDF[dist, {0, 0.2`3}]
Precision[0.2]
$MachinePrecision
CDF[dist, {0, 0.2}]
(*  0.47  *)
(*  MachinePrecision  *)
(*  15.9546  *)
(*  0.446357  *)
```

So with only three digits of initial and intermediate precision, we get the right answer, but with nearly 16 (initially), we do not.  Even assuming less than one digit of precision in the input, the correct output cannot be produced by the MachinePrecision computation.  (The function is monotonic over the interval used.)

```
NMinimize[{CDF[dist, {0, y}], 0.0 <= y <= 0.4}, y]
NMaximize[{CDF[dist, {0, y}], 0.0 <= y <= 0.4}, y]
(*  {0.437977, {y -> 0.}}  *)
(*  {0.465287, {y -> 0.4}}  *)
```

The discrepancy between the correct CDF (blue) and the MachinePrecision CDF (yellow) can be quite large.

```
Plot[{
    NIntegrate[ PDF[ MultinormalDistribution[
      {0, 0}, ({{1, 37/40}, {37/40, 1}})], {x, y}], 
      {x, -∞, 0}, {y, -∞, u}],
    CDF[dist, {0, u}]}, 
  {u, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(I've weakly checked that the large discrepancy is not a result of numerical integration.  Taking $m$ to be the off-diagonal element of the covariance matrix and assuming $0 < m < 1$, either the $x$ integral or the $y$ integral can be performed by `Integrate`, giving $\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi}} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{y^2}{2}} \text{erfc}\left(\frac{m y}{\sqrt{2-2 m^2}}\right)$ and $\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi }} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{u-m x}{\sqrt{2-2 m^2}}\right)+1\right)$, respectively.  Replacing the double numerical integral with the single numerical integral of either of these does not visibly change the graph.)

Also, [Karsten 7. is correct](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129916/huge-bug-involving-multinormaldistribution#comment350966_129922).  This discrepancy suddenly turns on for a critical value of the off-diagonal covariance elements near 0.925.

```
Plot[
  CDF[ MultinormalDistribution[
      {0, 0}, ({{1, SetPrecision[x, 15]}, {SetPrecision[x, 15], 1}})], 
    {0, 0.2`15}] - 
  CDF[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, ({{1, x}, {x, 1}})], 
    {0, 0.2}], 
  {x, 0.8, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This last is very strong evidence of a method switch introducing error, not precision loss.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was not aware that a different method is used for diagonal values larger than 0.925. Now the gap makes sense and only this method is corrupted.

Answer (score 11):

```
dist = MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, ({{1, 37/40}, {37/40, 1}})];
```

[`MachinePrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MachinePrecision.html): "Machine-precision numbers (often called simply 'machine numbers') always contain a fixed number of digits and maintain no information about precision. ... Machine-precision computations are typically performed using native floating-point unit and low-level numeric library operations that are typically very fast (particularly so in matrix arithmetic), but **provide no tracking of precision loss** that may occur due to numerical round-off and other factors during a computation. As a result, **machine arithmetic gives fast but numerically unvalidated results that may differ substantially from correct values**."

```
cdf1 = CDF[dist, {0, .2}]

(*  0.446357  *)
```

[`Arbitrary-Precision Numbers`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionNumbers.html) "When you do calculations with arbitrary-precision numbers, the Wolfram Language keeps track of precision at all points. In general, the Wolfram Language tries to give you results which have the highest possible precision, given the precision of the input you provided."

Changing `0.2` to an arbitrary-precision number

```
cdf2 = CDF[dist, {0, .2`15}]

(*  0.47007303261424  *)
```

Similarly, using `WorkingPrecision` when plotting

```
ContourPlot[
 CDF[dist, {x, y}], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
 PlotRange -> All,
 MaxRecursion -> 3,
 WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

[image]

Comment: Good explanation, but changing 37/40 to 37./40. makes the above plot wrong again. How to aviod that?

Comment: @fwgb Make sure you do not introduce any machine precision numbers.  `37.` is machine precision.  MachinePrecision is contagious and will turn everything else it touches into machine precision. `SetPrecision` can convert to arbitrary precision.  `Rationalize` can convert to exact.

Comment: @fwgb I think you might find this useful: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6421/121

Comment: I don't think that is the full story here. There is something else going wrong. I suspect that the implementation switches to a buggy implementation, when one parameter has `MachinePrecision`.

Comment: @Karsten7. Yes you're right. The funny thing is that for <= 36/40 everything is fine. For >= 37/40 the problem occurs.

Comment: @fwgb Glancing over the code, it looks like ``Statistics`MultinormalDistributionsDump`GenzDreznerWeselowskyBvnlCDF`` gets called, which contains an `If[ar < 0.925, ...]`. Test: ``Plot[CDF[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 
     0}, ({{1, SetPrecision[x, 15]}, {SetPrecision[x, 15], 1}})], {0, 
    0.2`15}] - 
  CDF[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, ({{1, x}, {x, 1}})], {0, 0.2}],
 {x, 0.8, 1}, PlotRange -> All]``