# Changing machine precision notebook-wide leads to peculiarities

Tags: numerics, evaluation, machine-precision, arbitrary-precision

For a project of mine it is preferrable to set notebook precision globally. I have done so by using the answer in [Global precision setting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6421/global-precision-setting).

The idea is to dynamically create a `Range` from variables created with this `$PreRead`, but a peculiarity occurs. The below code illustrates this: a rather trivial function with input variables is `SetDelayed`. However, on a fresh kernel `asdf` does not evaluate. The global variant outside `Module` however works fine. Is there any way to create the below functionality using this `$PreRead`? Or is there an alternative to the `$PreRead` method that can be used interchangeably?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

myGlobalPrecision = 2 $MachinePrecision;
$PreRead = (# /. 
     s_String /; 
       StringMatchQ[s, NumberString] && 
        Precision@ToExpression@s == MachinePrecision :> 
      s <> "`" <> ToString@Floor@myGlobalPrecision <> "." &);

asdf[PTsNo_, {xLBound_Real, xUBound_Real}] := Module[{xIncrements},
  xIncrements = 
   Range[xLBound, xUBound, (xUBound - xLBound)/(PTsNo - 1)]
  ]

ListPlotResolution = 20;
SpaceLowerBound = 0;
SpaceUpperBound = 10.;
xLBoundGlobal = SpaceLowerBound;
xUBoundGlobal = SpaceUpperBound;
PTsNoGlobal = 20;

asdf[ListPlotResolution, {SpaceLowerBound/1., SpaceUpperBound/1.}]

xIncrements = 
 Range[xLBoundGlobal, 
  xUBoundGlobal, (xUBoundGlobal - xLBoundGlobal)/(PTsNoGlobal - 1)]
```

Comment: Note that zero in arbitrary precision arithmetic is the `Integer` zero when computed thus: ``0/1.`20``.  Hence the second argument to `asdf` is not a list of `Real`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Interesting. That indeed does improve the situation...

Comment: @MichaelE2 How does one enforce `Real`ness of `0/1.``20`?

Comment: It's a good question.  ```0``20``` represents an underlfow less than $10^{-20}$. It computes as zero plus/minus an uncertainty in arbitrary precision arithmetic.  The only true (?) zero in arbitrary precision is the integer `0`.  So as far as argument patterns go, you could use `xLBound: 0 | _Real`.  There is also ``xLBound_?Internal`RealValuedNumberQ`` but it will allow `Integer` and `Rational` arguments as well.

Comment: Note that `N[0, myGlobalPrecision]` and `SetPrecision[0, myGlobalPrecision]` have the same problem as ``0/1.`20``.

Comment: @MichaelE2 It seems as if removing the `/1.` and using your Internal`RealValuedNumberQ trick solved the problem.